# How to disable a plugin in the replace function of CkEditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I want to disable the image-upload on some CKEditor `textareas`. I don't want to do this via config.js file as it will disable for all the `textareas`. How can I do this using the .replace method?

Example:

```
CKEDITOR.replace("meTextarea", {
   // what should I write here to disable the plugin?
});
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass options to the [`CKEDITOR.replace()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace) function:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('meTextarea', {
   removePlugins: 'filebrowser'
});
```

Read more about setting configuration here: [Setting Configuration](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration).

Answer (score 0):

if you are unable to disable if from their given function then try this thing in your css

```
.ck-file-dialog-button
{
  display:none !important;
}
```

this will hide image upload button without disturbing your UI.

```
.ck-dropdown{
    display:none !important;
}
```